# Manage multiple styles of main window in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nib, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

What's the best way to switch between multiple styles of main windows in cocoa?
I mean something like iTunes with its mini-player view and its normal sized view.
I want to layout different nib-files and let the user choose between the small one or the bigger one with more details.
Do I need a NSWindowController or is it ok to load nibs in the App Delegate like this:
`[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"BigWindow" owner:self];`

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `NSWindowController` to load a nib containing a window. This is because `NSWindowController` handles the nib memory management for you, which is otherwise somewhat painful.

If you just want to load a view from a nib use `NSViewController` instead.

Comment: hmm thanks, I try to share some logic between the windows. Both windows do the same thing, they just have a different size and look. when I use a NSWindowController for each window (xib-file) and assign the app delegate I got an instance of the app delegate for each window controller. I think I oversee something. There must be a simple way to do this (as it is done in fullscreen apps with different layout).

Comment: Your app controller should instantiate the window controllers programmatically and keep a reference to them (an ivar). What do you mean by "assign the app delegate"?

Comment: My app controller and delegate is the same. I instantiate a window controller and got it as an ivar of the delegate. In the xib file I have an app delegate object to make the connections to the IBActions in the app delegate. When I break into a method from the window I see that the app delegate ivars have the address 0x0. the app delegate itself has another address than in the 'appDidFinishLoading' method. When I call a method from the main menu everything is fine. So I messed up something. Is it wrong to have the app delegate in each xib to call the IBActions ?